# Continuity and its relationship with asymptotic spectral decay

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals

The asymptotic decay of the magnitude of the Fourier transform of a function appears always to be determined by its continuity properties as follows, with examples given in Fig. 1:

- Continuous integral, -20 dB / decade;
- Continuous function, -40 dB / decade;
- Continuous 1st derivative; -60 dB / decade;
- ...

How can this be expressed mathematically in a rigorous way, and proved?

[image]
*Figure 1. dB magnitude of the Fourier transform of a function as function of the base-10 logarithm of frequency for (from slowest to fastest decay) a rectangular pulse (turquoise), a single lobe of a cosine (purple), and Hann function (blue).*

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it would be sufficient to show that a discontinuous function in the time domain decays as $1/\omega$ in the frequency domain (e.g., $\textrm{rect}\Leftrightarrow\textrm{sinc}$), and then use the fact that each integration in the time domain adds a multiplicative factor of $1/j\omega$ in the frequency domain.

Comment: Yes, or start with a sum of shifted and scaled Dirac deltas and show that its spectrum never settles. Or is periodic if the delays are rational numbers.